# Using Bourbon in Sass File - Play Framework

Tags: playframework, sass, playframework-2.0, webjars

I have added the bourbon webjar to my build.sbt:

```
val Bourbon = "org.webjars.bower" % "bourbon" % "4.2.3"
```

In my sass file (app/assets/stylesheets/main.sass) I have the import:

```
@import "../../../target/web/web-modules/main/webjars/lib/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/bourbon"
```

I am somewhat uncomfortable with the `../` and the path length.

Interestingly it seems to be packaged into its own `app/assets/stylesheets` directory.

**Is there any other way to specify the import?**

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on implementing a [Sass plugin](https://github.com/irundaia/sbt-sassify) myself. I've made sure that webjars can be included easily.

Using this plugin, it should be possible to include a webjar library by:

```
@import "lib/<library name>/path/to/sass/stylesheet";
```

So for Bourbon in particular use for example:

```
@import "lib/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/bourbon";

// example of bourbon mixin usage
a.tooltip-anchor + .tooltip:after {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  top: -12px;
  @include triangle(6.5em 2.5em, #FF0000, down);
}
```